# Difference between SVM and MPM (example)

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, svm, minimax

I know the theorical difference between theses methods, but someone could give an example that make SVM != MPM? I think it's the same thing.

An image would be awesome.

SVM: Maximize margin between 2 samples classes

MPM: Minimize the probability of wrong classification

Thank you.

Comment: If you need an example to convince you that SVMs aren't the same as MPM, then you do not understand the theoretical difference between the methods. A picture is not going to make you sudden't understand what is really happening.

Comment: I 'know' the difference, but in practice it seems to be the same thing. I'd like to see an picture to make it overt.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jc4gF.png) is a link to the picture.

Comment: try to provide a hint about your answer. link or image wont help your solution to reach.